# How to convert true into Boolean.TRUE?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, jtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set Jtable/Column Renderer for booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879559/set-jtable-column-renderer-for-booleans)

Right now I have in my Jtable:

[image]

but I want to have:

[image]

Therefore ,I guess, I have to covert my trues/false's into object like:

```
  Object rowData[][] = { { "1", Boolean.TRUE }, { "2", Boolean.TRUE }, { "3", Boolean.FALSE },
      { "4", Boolean.TRUE }, { "5", Boolean.FALSE }, };
```

Right now I get the data like this:

```
    int i=0;
    data=new Object[tupel.size()][1];
    while(i<tupel.size()){
        row=tupel.get(i);
        data[i][0]=new Boolean(row.isTrueorFalse());//my "Boolean method"
        i++;
    }
}
```

So my question is:

How to convert my data into Objects so that I have diplayed the ticks?

**UPDATE**

The isTrueorFalse Method:

```
public boolean isTrueorFalse() {
        return isTrueorFalse;
}
```

Comment: Does your `row.isTrueorFalse()` method return `Integer` or `boolean` ?

Comment: boolean... So that I get true/false

Comment: Then what is the problem in the code ?

Comment: The thing is, I get in my table the names for true and false and not the ticks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JTable has built_in support for Boolean value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), then renderer/editor shows JCheckBox

have to override column in the [XxxTableModel with proper Column Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

```
@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
    return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
}
```

- [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10634914/714968)
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated your issue, short, runnable, compilable. otherwise every answers here could be shots to the dark

Comment: Overriding the `getColumnClass` is indeed the way to go

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that you want `data` as array like that then you can do below. I am not sure that is what you require though.

```
data[i][0]= i;
data[i][1] = row.isTrueorFalse();
```

You can then set data in table model like below

```
tableModel.set((Integer)data[i][0], (Boolean) data[i][1]);
```

Comment: ok I understand, first i get the data, but then how do you convert it into an Object to get the ticks. Pls would you be so kind to explain it a little bit further?

Comment: @maximus you need to set values to tableModel first as index and second as boolean then it will display check boxes

Answer (score 2):

```
    data[i][0]=Boolean.valueOf(row.isTrueorFalse());
```

this won't create any new objects of Boolean, just Boolean.TRUE or Boolean.FALSE.

Comment: thx for your answer! but then how to get the ticks?

Answer (score 2):

You should create your own [Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

Look for the following point:

> If the programmer does not provide a table model object, JTable automatically creates an instance of DefaultTableModel.

And the following:

> SimpleTableDemo's automatically created table model, on the other hand, does not know that the # of Years column contains numbers (which should generally be right aligned and have a particular format). It also does not know that the Vegetarian column contains boolean values, which can be represented by check boxes.

The construction should be something as follows:

```
JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
```

instead of using `JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)` or `JTable(Vector rowData, Vector columnNames)`. In this case it uses the `DefaultTableModel`, which is not intelligent enough to display your booleans as ticks (check boxes).

It also has a sample code to help you achieve what you are trying to achieve.